# unlink() doesn't delete the uploaded file

Tags: custom-field, uploads

I'm using this code in my plugin to add an extra field to the user profiles so that the user can upload an image. It uploads the file perfectly but the only problem is the part that has to delete the previous uploaded image doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById('your-profile');
    form.encoding = "multipart/form-data";
    form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
</script>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="profile_photo">Upload your profile photo</label></th>
        <td>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="profile_photo" id="profile_photo" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save">
            <input type="submit" name="submitprofilephoto" id="submitprofilephoto" class="button" value="بارگذاری"> 
        </p>
            <span class="description">
            <?php
            $author_profile_photo = get_author_profile_photo($user->ID);
            if(is_array($author_profile_photo)):
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $author_profile_photo["url"];?>" target="_blank">
                    <img src="<?php echo $author_profile_photo["file"];?>" height="100" width="100" />
                </a>
            <?php
            endif;
            ?>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php 
}

function get_author_profile_photo($user_ID) {

$author_data = get_the_author_meta( 'profile_photo', $user_ID );
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$author_data["file"] = $uploads["baseurl"] . $author_data["file"];
return $author_data;
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;

$upload=$_FILES['profile_photo'];
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['submitprofilephoto']!='') { 
    if ($upload['tmp_name'] && file_is_displayable_image( $upload['tmp_name'] )) {

            // handle the uploaded file
            $overrides = array('test_form' => false);
            $file=wp_handle_upload($upload, $overrides);
            $file["file"] = $uploads["subdir"]."/".basename($file["url"]);

            // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just Images.  
            $supported_types = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png' );  

            // Get the file type of the upload  
            $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($upload['name']));  
            $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];  

            // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.  
            if( $file && in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types) ) {  
                if($upload['size'] > 204800) {
                     wp_die('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Maximum size allowed is 200KB.');
                }

                //remove previous uploaded file
                $author_profile_photo = get_author_profile_photo($user_id);
                @unlink($author_profile_photo["file"]);
                // I even tried unlink without the @ and it still doesn't delete the file!

                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'profile_photo', $file );

        } else wp_die('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Allowd image formats are JPEG, JPG and PNG.');

    } elseif (!file_is_displayable_image( $upload['tmp_name'] )) wp_die('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The file you selected is not an image!');
}
}
?>
```

Where or what is the problem?

Comment: The WordPress way would be `wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Kudos for showing what you did try. Just a hint for your next Questions: try to isolate the problem before posting the code, see the guide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If I were you, I'd follow @toscho's advice, and if you can't make it work, you can update the Question ([edit]) with the new code.

Comment: how do I get the attachment id?!

Comment: I don't think the code above does give the uploaded file an id?! does it? if it does, then how are we suppose to get the id of it?!

Comment: Please write your solution as an **answer** and [accept this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: get_author_profile_photo is not a wordpress native function, is it your own or some plugin?

Comment: @toscho That function calls `unlink` and if that doesn't work on their php installation, it will likely not work with wp_delete_attachment either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! the problem is the path is not right! Thanks to this post : Alow users to delete uploaded images inside backend?

this function below helped :

```
 function url_to_path_test($url){
    $url=str_replace(rtrim(get_site_url(),'/').'/', ABSPATH, $url);
   return $url;
   }
```

So in my code if you change the remove previous image like this it will work :

```
  //remove previous uploaded file
  $author_profile_photo = get_author_profile_photo($user_id);
  $url=str_replace(rtrim(get_site_url(),'/').'/', ABSPATH, $author_profile_photo["file"]);
  @unlink($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the code below is a much better solution :

```
 //remove previous uploaded file
  $author_data = get_the_author_meta( 'profile_photo', $user_id );
  $author_data["file"] = $uploads["path"] . $author_data["file"];

  $imagepath = $author_data["file"];
  @unlink($imagepath);
```

Answer (score -3):

Here give full url of your file where it is located.

```
      unlink(public_path('file/to/delete'))
```

as you are just providing file name in your code

```
    @unlink($author_profile_photo["file"]);
```

and with if you want to prevent generating an error if the file does not exist.

Comment: please don't just dump code as an answer, add some text that explains why is it solving the problem